# Shifting position of sql query results

Tags: sql-server, select, case

I know the question seems to be a bit confusing. i have a query that return the following result :

[image]

is there a way to shift results so i can have something like : all null values will be replaced by the values below ? only room service midi has a null value, all the rest are shifted. is there a way to replace that.

My query :

```
select pc.code, pc.description,
CASE 
                           WHEN g.description like 'NOURRITURE' and pc.description like 'PETIT DEJEUNER' THEN COALESCE(sum(ta.price),0)
                           WHEN g.description like 'NOURRITURE' and pc.description like 'BANQUET' THEN COALESCE(sum(ta.price),0)
                           WHEN g.description like 'NOURRITURE' and pc.description like 'CASABLANCA CAFE MIDI' THEN COALESCE(sum(ta.price),0)
                           WHEN g.description like 'NOURRITURE' and pc.description like 'CASABLANCA CAFE MATIN' THEN COALESCE(sum(ta.price),0)
                           WHEN g.description like 'NOURRITURE' and pc.description like 'CASABLANCA CAFE SOIR' THEN COALESCE(sum(ta.price),0)
                           WHEN g.description like 'NOURRITURE' and pc.description like 'CASABLANCA CAFE BAR' THEN COALESCE(sum(ta.price),0)
                           WHEN g.description like 'NOURRITURE' and pc.description like 'ROOM SERVICE NUIT' THEN COALESCE(sum(ta.price),0)
                           WHEN g.description like 'NOURRITURE' and pc.description like 'ROOM SERVICE MIDI' THEN COALESCE(sum(ta.price),0)
                           WHEN g.description like 'NOURRITURE' and pc.description like 'ROOM SERVICE SOIR' THEN COALESCE(sum(ta.price),0)
                           WHEN g.description like 'NOURRITURE' and pc.description like 'ROOM SERVICE PDJ' THEN COALESCE(sum(ta.price),0)
                           WHEN g.description like 'NOURRITURE' and pc.description like 'XO LOUNGE/MIDI' THEN COALESCE(sum(ta.price),0)
                           WHEN g.description like 'NOURRITURE' and pc.description like 'BANQUET LUNCH' THEN COALESCE(sum(ta.price),0)
                           WHEN g.description like 'NOURRITURE' and pc.description like 'BANQUET DINNER' THEN COALESCE(sum(ta.price),0)
                           WHEN g.description like 'NOURRITURE' and pc.description like 'TABAC' THEN COALESCE(sum(ta.price),0)
                           WHEN g.description like 'NOURRITURE' and pc.description like 'XO LOUNGE/SOIR' THEN COALESCE(sum(ta.price),0)
                           WHEN g.description like 'NOURRITURE' and pc.description like 'Terasse Bleue' THEN COALESCE(sum(ta.price),0)
                           WHEN g.description like 'NOURRITURE' and pc.description like 'SPA' THEN COALESCE(sum(ta.price),0)
                           WHEN g.description like 'NOURRITURE' and pc.description like 'Seven' THEN COALESCE(sum(ta.price),0)
                           WHEN g.description like 'NOURRITURE' and pc.description like 'MINI BAR' THEN COALESCE(sum(ta.price),0)
                           WHEN g.description like 'NOURRITURE' and pc.description like 'CHEZ DADA' THEN COALESCE(sum(ta.price),0)

                        END  as SumPriceFood,

                        CASE 
                           WHEN g.description like 'BOISSON' and pc.description like 'PETIT DEJEUNER' THEN sum(ta.price)
                           WHEN g.description like 'BOISSON' and pc.description like 'BANQUET' THEN sum(ta.price)
                           WHEN g.description like 'BOISSON' and pc.description like 'CASABLANCA CAFE MIDI' THEN sum(ta.price)
                           WHEN g.description like 'BOISSON' and pc.description like 'CASABLANCA CAFE MATIN' THEN sum(ta.price)
                           WHEN g.description like 'BOISSON' and pc.description like 'CASABLANCA CAFE SOIR' THEN sum(ta.price)
                           WHEN g.description like 'BOISSON' and pc.description like 'CASABLANCA CAFE BAR' THEN sum(ta.price)
                           WHEN g.description like 'BOISSON' and pc.description like 'ROOM SERVICE NUIT' THEN sum(ta.price)
                           WHEN g.description like 'BOISSON' and pc.description like 'ROOM SERVICE MIDI' THEN sum(ta.price)
                           WHEN g.description like 'BOISSON' and pc.description like 'ROOM SERVICE SOIR' THEN sum(ta.price)
                           WHEN g.description like 'BOISSON' and pc.description like 'ROOM SERVICE PDJ' THEN sum(ta.price)
                           WHEN g.description like 'BOISSON' and pc.description like 'XO LOUNGE/MIDI' THEN sum(ta.price)
                           WHEN g.description like 'BOISSON' and pc.description like 'BANQUET LUNCH' THEN sum(ta.price)
                           WHEN g.description like 'BOISSON' and pc.description like 'BANQUET DINNER' THEN sum(ta.price)
                           WHEN g.description like 'BOISSON' and pc.description like 'TABAC' THEN sum(ta.price)
                           WHEN g.description like 'BOISSON' and pc.description like 'XO LOUNGE/SOIR' THEN sum(ta.price)
                           WHEN g.description like 'BOISSON' and pc.description like 'Terasse Bleue' THEN sum(ta.price)
                           WHEN g.description like 'BOISSON' and pc.description like 'SPA' THEN sum(ta.price)
                           WHEN g.description like 'BOISSON' and pc.description like 'Seven' THEN sum(ta.price)
                           WHEN g.description like 'BOISSON' and pc.description like 'MINI BAR' THEN sum(ta.price)
                           WHEN g.description like 'BOISSON' and pc.description like 'CHEZ DADA' THEN sum(ta.price)

                        END  as SumPriceBoisson
                           from trans_articles ta, transactions t, profit_centers pc, article_causals ac, groups g, articles a
                           where t.id = ta.transaction_id
                           and pc.id = t.profit_center_id 
                           and ta.causal_id = ac.id
                           and g.id = a.group_a_id
                           and a.id = ta.article_id 
                           and ac.causal_type = 1                         
                           and ac.code in(103)
                           group by pc.code, pc.description, g.description
```

Thank you for reading

Comment: what would your expected output look like?  how are you ordering the rows to know what the value "below" is?

Comment: post your code and not the result only... if you hide the code you will not have any help because you are preventing anyone to help you.

Comment: You need to group by the "description" column.

Comment: i already applied the group by clause but same results.. please see my query

Answer (score 0):

Try the following;

```
SELECT   code
        ,description
        ,SUM(sumpricefood) sumpricefood
        ,SUM(sumpriceboisson) AS sumpriceboisson
GROUP BY code
        ,description
```

To shift results together based on the code and description you need to [group](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) the results together.